# Why will Rhythmbox not add or import songs since 13.04 install?

Tags: 13.04, music, rhythmbox, ipod

Since I installed 13.04 Ubuntu (12.04 before) I have not been able to add or import music to either of my iPods (4th & 5th generation). I can play music with Rhythmbox. Rhythmbox recognizes iPods. Cannot drag or import without crashing. No error codes. Have tried most variations of Preferred format. I have spent many many hours research, including Ask Ubuntu. Any new suggestions? DB

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Rythmbox? Upgrades can sometimes break apps.

Comment: Have you tried using Banshee instead or installing an older .deb package of Rhythmbox? That may help.

Comment: try installing `gst-plugins-bad1.0` & `gst-plugins-ugly1.0`.